# .net Micro for ARM M3 STM32F103ZD

Tags: c#, .net, .net-micro-framework

I'm new to this, but I'd like to develop C# .net Micro apps for microcontroller ARM M3 STM32F103ZD.

I found development kit STM32F103ZE ARM-CM3 Board, link http://www.embedinfo.com/en/list.asp?id=31

Can anyone tell me, if it's possible to develop C# .net Micro apps on this kit.

Thanks

Comment: Wow, that site was without competition the slowest site of the week. Is it hosted on the ARM board itself?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [LinkSprite](http://www.linksprite.com/product/product.php?lang=en&class1=30&class2=91&class3=103) uses a very close variant, the STM32F103ZE and makes their .NET Micro Framework firmware available for [download](http://www.linksprite.com/download/download.php?lang=en&class1=31&class2=54), including sourcecode for the 3.1 .NET MF. This should at least make the porting job easier.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely to be possible, it is also likely to be a bit of work if you don't find a ready made port of .NET Micro Framework for your hardware. If you don't find a port you have to spend a while with the [.NET Micro Framework 4.0 Porting Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=16fa5d31-a583-4c0d-af74-f4d5e235d5bc), the download page is specifically mentioning Cortex processors.

But if you don't need any explicit stuff from that board it might be easier to order one of the kits from the [Turnkey Hardware](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/netmf/hardware/default.aspx) site, the Fez kits seems to be fairly popular.

Comment: That will be easier, but in my company we are going to use specialy this type of microcontroler, so I have to get used to it.